# ILCrashreporter breaks Sparkle updates

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, sparkle

I have just added ILCrashReporter-NG to my application to log application crashes. Unfortunately it seems to have broken my Sparkle updates (Sparkle gives an error when the appcast has downloaded and the Install button is clicked). I have added the ILCrashReporter launchReporterForCompany: report addr: method to applicationDidFinishLaunching. Does anyone have any experience of implementing these two frameworks together and if so, is this a problem that you encountered.

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 0):

I use the two together without any problems. What's the error that you get? Did you change anything else besides adding Sparkle?

The only time I've had the update fail, as you describe, was after changing my bundle id so that the bundle id in the update and the application didn't match.

Comment: It's been such a long time I can't remember. I think I started from scratch and everything workeed hunky dory so I suspect it might have been a stuipid error like the one you mention.